# Changing names of multiple folders in a Shell Script

Tags: shell

I started learning Shell Scripting. I want to rename folder names sequentially. I have some folders from 1, 2 , 3 ... 1000.  Now I want to rename it 1501,1502, ... 2500 respectively by shell script. How it can be done.
 Thanks for your help

Comment: folder 1, 2, 3, ... 1000, you have 1000 folders, rename to 1500, 1501, 1502, ... 2500, you will 1001 folders, guess you mean rename to 1501, 1502, 1503, ... 2500

Comment: Please accept the answers if they worked otherwise ask for more details. It is not a good practise to ask and ignore once you get information.

Answer (score 2):

if you start thinking about it, its really easy, ill explain a bit:
you go through every number from 1 to 1500
and rename it to its `index + 1500`:

to add numbers you can use arithmetic operations if you are on `bash`
or the command `bc` if you are only on shell environment.
(i'll use `bc` because it should work everywhere)

use command `seq 1500` -> output is: `1 2 3 ... 1500`
make a for loop: `for f in $(seq 1500); do ###later###; done`

so the current number (`$f`) is the folder name

the new name will be the current number (`$f`) + 1500:
(because you want folder 1 to be new folder 1501)
`newname=$(echo "$f + 1500" | bc)`

then you only have to say `mv $f $newname`
finished :)

**final script:**
inline version:

```
for f in $(seq 1500); do mv $f $(echo "$f + 1500" | bc); done
```

'nicer' (better readable) version:

```
for f in $(seq 1500); do
    newname=$(echo "$f + 1500" | bc)
    mv $f $newname
done
```

if you want to use bash arithmetic operations:
replace `$(echo "$f + 1500" | bc)` with `$(($f + 1500))`

i hope i could help you a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

If your folder exactly with the same names, below code will work... you can improvise it for other situations. If the naming and renaming pattern varies, you may have to do it slightly differently.

```
for (( sourcedir=1,destdir=1501; sourcedir<=1000;sourcedir++,destdir++ ))
do
   mv "$sourcedir" "$destdir"
done
```

Comment: Thank you So much. It will also help me for better understanding.